# JoinColumn annotation creates column on same table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am new in Hibernate and trying to learn it. I am confused about the usage of @JoinColumn. I know that it creates a column to associate two entities. What I have tried is :

1. Having two class Person and House
2. Person class has an set of Houses with OneToMany relation

In Person Class:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")  // this creates a FK on house table  with this name
    private Set<House> houses = new HashSet<House>();
```

This creates a column with name `person_id` on `House` table.

In House Class:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "house_id")
    private Person person;
```

This creates `house_id` column again on `House` table. But I was expecting to see this column on `Person` table. Why it works like this?

I was thinking @JoinColumn annotation creates a join column on the table which is the entity which we applied this annotation to. So in this case for the Person class, it created person_id on house table and for the second one I was expecting to see house_id on person class. But it also creates it on house table. So I am confused.

So how it works actually ?

Comment: have you tried to specify the attribute `mappedBy`, ex: `@OneToMany(mappedBy="houses")`?

Comment: yeah i tried it and on that way it is less confusing actually, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`@JoinColumn` creates a column **where it makes sense**.

For `@OneToMany` with `@JoinColumn`, the join column needs to go to the target entity table, i.e. `House`. If the column was created in the source entity table, i.e. `Person`, one person could only have a single house assigned, so it would not be a one-to-many association.

Conversely, for `@ManyToOne` with `@JoinColumn`, the join column needs to go to the source entity (i.e. `House`). If the column went to the `Person` table instead, and you assigned a given person to one house, the `PERSON.HOUSE_ID` column would get set to the id of that house. Then, there would be no way of assigning another house to that same person (as the `PERSON.HOUSE_ID` column would already be 'used'). This is essentially the same problem as before, but seen from the 'house' side of the association.

Comment: I was searching for this whole day. Thanks a ton man :)

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `@JoinColumn(name = "house_id")` with `@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")`  supposing house has a column named person_id

then remove `@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")`
and in OneToMany annotation add the attribute mappedBy

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
```

in this way hibernate will search all house where person attribute matches with current person_id